# Redirect from bootstrap tab to another Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tabs

I have two tabs in a template.In one tab I can create attendance(tab1) in another tab I can view attendance(tab2) that was created previously.Now when I create a attendance successfully I want to check if the attendance is valid and if valid I want to redirect from tab 1 to tab 2. How can I achieve this in Django? 
Here's my template and view snippet
https://gist.github.com/quantum2020/c55adeb3b8c2ee0ac2d99ff46f5699e8

https://gist.github.com/quantum2020/2cb28233608c3a219ff97762e1fd62be

Comment: Add your code here.

Comment: If you just want to redirect to the view attendance page every time you create a new attendance, just add a call to `redirect()` when the attendance is valid. Here's a link for the docs on redirect -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect